# NoReverseMatch when using django forms

Tags: python, django

I am struggling a long time now with Django forms. I had my form working without using Django forms, but it seemed better to use it. I get a reverse error, full error:

```
Reverse for 'dish_update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I am afraid i am overlooking the obvious here, but some help would be very appreciated. Here is my code:

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Dish


class DishForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Dish
    fields = ('dishName', 'dishStars',)
```

html

```
<h1>{{ dish.dishName }}</h1> 
<h4>{{ dish.dishDescription }}</h4>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<a href="{% url "dish_update" %}"></a>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<dish_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<dish_id>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.dish_update,        name='dish_update'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Dish
from .forms import DishForm


def index(request):
    dishes = Dish.objects.all()
    context = {'dishes': dishes}
    return render(request, 'bbqcontrol/index.html', context)


def detail(request, dish_id):
    dish = get_object_or_404(Dish, pk=dish_id)
    return render(request, 'bbqcontrol/detail.html', {'dish': dish})


def dish_update(request):
    form = DishForm()
    return render(request, 'bbqcontrol/dish_update.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: None of your code matches the error. Where do you try to reverse the `'results'` view?

Comment: the results code is old code. i deleted it now, error stays about the same thing, but instead of results its now dish_update. I will update the full error in  question

Comment: By any chance, are you using any namespace in the parent URL file?

Comment: Yeah, the index file has a namespace. But also after removing it, same error stays. After adding namespace to detail.html, i got a slightly different error though:             Reverse for 'dish_update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'bbqcontrol/(?P<dish_id>[0-9]+)/update/$']'

Answer (score 0):

Your URL `dish_update` takes an argument `dish_id` which is not present in `{% url "dish_update" %}`. That's why the reverser fails.

Update your URL tag by including the object's ID as an argument:

```
<a href="{% url "dish_update" dish.id %}"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, of course it needs the id. I added it, i think i am a step further, but something else is expected also. Now the error is:   Reverse for 'dish_update' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: If you remove the namespace from your root urls, and include the dish id in the template, then hopefully it will work.